# Java/Mysql..SQLException: A table must have at least 1 column SQLState: 42000 VendorError: 1113

Tags: java, mysql

I have an application that connects to the database, creates a table if it doesn't already exist by name, and adds the new registering users' information so that I can hash the passwords to my login frame, and match them with the database which will also be hashed. Currently I have the following error code.

```
SQLException: A table must have at least 1 column
SQLState: 42000
VendorError: 1113
```

with this code snippet

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;

public class LoadDriver {

public static void sqlDriver(String[] args) throws InstantiationException,
        IllegalAccessException, ClassNotFoundException {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    try {

        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();

        Connection conn = null;
        conn =

        DriverManager
                .getConnection(
                        "jdbc:mysql://dbname.dbwebsite.com:3306",
                        "user", "H45H3DP455W0RD");

        java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt = conn
                .prepareStatement("USE db_name");
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt2 = conn.
                prepareStatement("CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_table");
        java.sql.PreparedStatement pstmt3 = conn.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO db_table (user, pass, repass, name, lame, dob, gender, adds, apt, city, zip, phone, email) VALUES(id int NOT NULL auto_increment, VARCHAR(30) user, VARCHAR(30) pass, VARCHAR(30) repass, VARCHAR(30) name, VARCHAR(30) lname, VARCHAR(10) dob, TEXT gender, TEXT addr, TEXT apt, TEXT city, TEXT zip, TEXT phone, VARCHAR(30) email, PRIMARY KEY(id));");


        pstmt.executeUpdate();
        pstmt2.executeUpdate();
        pstmt3.executeUpdate();

        ResultSet rs = pstmt.executeQuery();
        rs.close();


    } catch (SQLException ex) {
        // handle any errors
        System.out.println("SQLException: " + ex.getMessage());
        System.out.println("SQLState: " + ex.getSQLState());
        System.out.println("VendorError: " + ex.getErrorCode());
    }


}

}
```

In the main class

```
JButton registerSend = new JButton("Submit");
                            regFrame.add(registerSend, BorderLayout.SOUTH);
                            registerSend
                                    .addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                                        @Override
                                        public void actionPerformed(
                                                ActionEvent r) {

                                            JFrame gameFrame = new JFrame(
                                                    "Welcome to Heavy Evil");
                                            gameFrame.setBounds(0, 0, 1200,
                                                    800);
                                            gameFrame.setVisible(true);

                                            int id;
                                            String user = tagText.getText();
                                            char[] pass = passText.getPassword();
                                            char[] repass = passConfirm
                                                    .getPassword();
                                            String name = heyText.getText();
                                            String lname = heyText2
                                                    .getText();
                                            String dob = userAge.getText();
                                            String gender = genDer
                                                    .getText();
                                            String addr = heyText3
                                                    .getText();
                                            String apt = heyText4.getText();
                                            String city = heyText5
                                                    .getText();
                                            String zip = heyText6.getText();
                                            String phone = heyText7
                                                    .getText();
                                            String email = heyText8
                                                    .getText();

                                            try {
                                                LoadDriver.sqlDriver(null);


                                            } catch (InstantiationException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch
                                                // block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch
                                                // block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
                                                // TODO Auto-generated catch
                                                // block
                                                e.printStackTrace();
                                            }

                                        }
                                    });
```

Comment: First read the error message. _A table must have at least 1 column._

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_table
```

You have not specified any columns, which is exactly what the error message told you.  The correct syntax is

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS db_table (
    column_name1        datatype,
    column_name2        datatype,
    etc.
)
```

Comment: I have @SuppressWarnings in my main class is that ok or should i create it in a result set?

Comment: Sorry, but that question makes no sense. @SuppressWarnings is unrelated to anything to do with SQL.

Comment: You seem to have missed the point of my answer. The syntax of your `create table` statement is incorrect.  Did you fix that?

Comment: Well I will but it's not going to work unless I can add my JTextArea.method to my database file..

Comment: "... Add my JTextArea method to my database file" -- again, that doesn't make sense.  You should probably ask a new question about this, and try to explain clearly what you don't understand.

Comment: I want to but it would be the same code snippet... Where I have LoadDriver.sqlDriver(); in my main .Java file I need to add a class or method in my sqlDriver method so that my prepared statements link to the Strings and char[]

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16679210/how-to-pass-textfield-from-main-class-to-another-class